# Listview 2 columns WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Another newbie question. I would like to open a text file and bind to a listview(WPF) with 2 columns, ID and Details. Here is a copy of the txt file. So ID will contain host and os name and so on and Details will contain the info to the right. This list is much larger, but you get the point. Yes I am new to c# and WPF. Your help is appreciated..

```
Host Name:                 MD1HXQTC
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
BIOS Version:              Hewlett-Packard M70 Ver. 01.08, 3/16/2015
```

Comment: And you didn't try anything yourself yet? There is plenty of documentation and examples of the WPF ListView out there.

Comment: SO would love to help but in order to do so you need to make an attempt yourself. break it down into sections and then write some code to do each step. at that point if you get an error or something then by all means come back and post a question.

Comment: "I have tried some things", so what? Tell us where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Not sure how to separate the items into an array. From there I am not sure how to bind the array to the columns.

Comment: go to google and type that in... how to parse delimited text into something with C#
then write code and if it doesnt work then post that code and ask for help

Comment: After that, start reading about MVVM and how it's used with WPF. Then read up about WPF data binding and data templating. Finally, create a view model that resembles your data, read the text file into this view model, and bind the controls in your DataTemplates to the view model. Sounds like a lot to learn? Well, it is, but you can't avoid learning.

Comment: @ Clemens, I will take a look, this is the info I need to get rolling, Yes very green I am. Thanks

Comment: @Metrics, please do not take me the wrong way. not trying to be combative. it is ok to be green but here you need to have done some leg work not just ask for "write my code" your best efforts will be to break down each task into simple steps. accomplish that step (ask for help if needed) then take the next step. so start with parsing the data then get the data to something that can be used and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Created My Class***

```
public class Gambit
{
    public string GetID { get; set; }
    public string GetDetails { get; set; }
}
```

***Added Observable Collection***

```
private ObservableCollection<Gambit> gambitCollection = new ObservableCollection<Gambit>();
```

***Wrote method to import txt file and bind objects***

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openfiledialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        openfiledialog.FileName = ""; // Default file name
        openfiledialog.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
        openfiledialog.Filter = "txt files (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show open file dialog box



        bool? result = openfiledialog.ShowDialog();

        // Process open file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {

            var fileName = openfiledialog.FileName;

            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName);

            string line = "";

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var splitLine = line.Split(':');


                if (splitLine.Count() > 1)
                {
                    gambitCollection.Add(new Gambit() { GetID = splitLine[0].Trim(), GetDetails = splitLine[1].Trim() });
                }
            }

        }
```

***Binded Itemsource to Collection***

```
ListViewRPMInfo.ItemsSource = gambitCollection;
```

Thank you to Babgev for getting me started and all others who pointed me in directions.

Answer (score 7):

The ListView is a descendant of the ListBox that allows to define custom views rather than a straight list.

The easiest way to get a list with columns is to have a GridView as the view of your ListView.

So if you have a class like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public string SecondProperty { get; set; }
}

//Actually you will also need your setters to raise the PropertyChanged event but it's not in the scope of the question.
```

You can declare your ListView as follows: (notice the DisplayMemberBindings have the names of my properties)

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Property"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstProperty}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Second Property"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SecondProperty}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Then you will need to make your collection of SomeClass to be the ItemsSource of the ListView.

Comment: I have been trying to split the txt file into an array, using ":" split on char. Not sure what my data structure is supposed to look like for the listview. Not used to OOP. Been procedural programming for about 10 years. Just a heads up, I need someone to walk me through this...not wanting someone to just right the code, I am learning and very very green..Thanks in advance. Any advice gives me the legs to work and run with this.